# How to plot a PCA table

Tags: r, pca, ggplot2, pcamixdata

I'm studying PCA method with the package `PCAmixdata` because I have a dataset with numerical and categorical variable. This is my example code in R:

```
library(dplyr)
library(PCAmixdata)

data <- starwars
db_quali <- as.data.frame(starwars[,4:6])
db_quanti <- as.data.frame(starwars[,2:3])

pca_table <- PCAmix(X.quanti = db_quanti,
                    X.quali = db_quali,
                    rename.level=TRUE,
                    graph = TRUE)
Gender <- factor(data$gender)

par(xpd=TRUE,mar=rep(8,4))
plot(pca_table ,choice="ind",label=FALSE,
     posleg=xy.coords(2,-10), main="Observations", coloring.ind = Gender)
```

I know that the function `ggplot` can be used only with `data.frame` and at the moment I have a `list`. Is there a way to convert `pca_table` into a `data.frame` to use the function `ggplot`?

I want to do this because in my original dataset I have many classes and with the function plot I have a limited set of colors, so a color could correspond to more than one class.